# Checked Value is not getting highlighted for radiobutton

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

I have below RadioButton Component

```
import React from 'react';

export default class RadioButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            selectedRadioButton :'Fact'
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) =>{
        this.setState({
            selectedRadioButton : event.target.value
        });
       this.props.handleSelect(event);       
    } 

    render() {
        console.log('im in render',this.state.selectedRadioButton);
        return (
            <div>           
            <input type="radio" name="value"  value={this.props.value} onClick={ e => this.handleChange(e) } 
                  checked={this.props.value === this.state.selectedRadioButton ? true : false}/>
            <label>{this.props.value}</label>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Im using radiobutton in  'BaseMeasure' Component as below

```
handleRadioSelect = (event) => {
        console.log('base measure event',event.target);       
        this.props.checkedRadioValue(event);
    }
<RadioButton value="Fact"  handleSelect = { this.handleRadioSelect }/>
<RadioButton value="Dimension" handleSelect = { this.handleRadioSelect } />
```

Using BaseMeasure Component in other file as

```
checkedValue(event) {
        console.log('in editor',event.target.value);
         this.setState({selectedRadioValue: event.target.value});
         if(this.state.selectedRadioValue === 'Dimension' ){
             this.fetchAllFieldsOnTablesRelatedToFactTable();
         }
         else{
             this.fetchFieldsOnOneFactTable();
            }
    }

    <BaseMeasure factTableData={ this.state.baseTablevalues } 
                                             diagnosisData = {this.state.diagnosisValues}  
                                             checkedRadioValue = {this.checkedValue}/>
```

Not able to see the checked value in UI after selecting radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

state is changing when you click on buttons or not?

Comment: Yes..state is changing

Comment: try something easy to check if did mistake with props:
checked={this.state.selectedRadioButton === 'Dimension' ? true : false}/>